# 200 Input Smart Multimeter Project

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, adc, programmable-logic, test-equipment

First off, thanks for taking the time to read this and help out.

Here's a quick overview of what I am trying to design. I have a break out box that has 200 female probe inputs. Each input is numbered, and I have to take continuity / resistance measurements across a whole range of potential combinations. Sometimes, the polarity will need to be reversed (ex: pin 34 to 80 and another measurement of pin 80 to 34, high and low side respectively) due to active components inside what I am trying to measure. I would like to automate this process, and compare the resistance of each connection to expected bounds.

In my head, I think a solution looks somethings like this:
200 inputs to header pins -> PCB to route header pins to BGA CPLD -> CPLD has input selectors and routes a selected signal to each output pin accordingly -> the outputs go to a resistor network that acts as an auto-ranging multimeter which is controlled by an Arduino that has the expected measurements inside to compare with. Results will be saved to a CSV file and anomalies will be displayed on an LCD screen.

Will a CPLD be able to route the analog signals to the arduino properly? I'm fairly new at digital / analog design and greatly appreciate all help. Thank you!

Comment: I just skimmed and may have missed important details. But it almost sounds like a full crossbar switching system and perhaps with relays given that I've no idea to which all these inputs might be attached. (Active components is all I have, but I don't know if this excludes any capacitance or inductance or what the currents might look like over time, etc.) And I don't really have any idea what you are measuring, either, because "continuity/resistance" alone doesn't seem appropriate for "active devices" in a black box so to speak. So I'm just confused, I guess.

Comment: Active components just refers to the fact that for two pins, there will have to be two measurements made by the multimeter portion of the device, reversing the polarity of the measurement. For a current to be put through the unknown resistance in the black box to obtain a resistance value, some of the active components in the box have diodes which would change the reading of the multimeter as opposed to if we were measuring a resistor in the black box or some other passive, bidirectional component.

Comment: A cpld won’t route analog signals. The old skool solution of relays is hard to beat. It was commonly used on test jigs to switch various nodes to a gpib multimeter. Reed relays for small signals.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:digital-logic] as well as [tag:adc]? (Devices I'd call *active* have at least one part of one characteristic curve showing a negative impedance. I'd call a diode *non-linear*.)

Answer (score 0):

For each probe, I'd want a pair of current sources or a bidirectional one: say, ±1 mA.
For each probe D in turn,

- Drive +1 mA into each probe, drive D low (? expect at least 200 mA needed. Alternatively, try to *drive* -210 mA), sample *all* probes. (Including D for a sanity check: Did *drive* succeed? D might be connected to V<sub>supply</sub>/GND after all.)
  Drive D high(/+ 10 mA?), sample once more.
- Drive -1 mA into each probe, drive D low, sample.
  Drive D high, sample one more time.

This leaves you with a mere 160k samples that should allow to tell what's what.